# What is the barycenter of a closed Riemannian surface?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\Sigma$ be a closed Riemannian surface. I read a paper which said:

**We let $\Sigma_k$ denote the family of formal sums
$$
\Sigma_k=\sum_{i=1}^k t_i \delta_{x_i} ; \quad t_i \geq 0, \quad \sum_{i=1}^k t_i=1 ; \quad x_i \in \Sigma,
$$
endowed with the weak topology of distributions. This is known in literature as the formal set of barycenters of $\Sigma$ (of order $k$ ).**

I have no idea about this paragraph, what is this $\delta_{x_i}$?

And what is **endowed with the weak topology of distributions**?

At first I thought it was a Dirac function but it seems that $\Sigma_k$ is a set not a function. Could you give me some clear definitions? I checked the definition on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Generalized_barycentric_coordinates) but there is no introduction on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole discussion has nothing to do with the fact that $\Sigma$ is a Riemann surface: it applies to any manifold.
For $x\in \Sigma$, $\delta_x$ is the Dirac mass at $x$, that is the distribution $\delta_x \in \mathcal{D}(\Sigma) = \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\Sigma)^*$ (the dual of the space of smooth functions), acting on smooth functions $f \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M)$ by
$$
\langle \delta_x,f\rangle = f(x).
$$
Note that $\delta_x$ is **not** a function, it is a [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)).
This way, we have a correspondence $x \leftrightarrow \delta_x$.
Through this correspondence, a barycenter "$\sum t_i x_i$", which makes no sense in $\Sigma$, can be thought of as $\sum t_i \delta_{x_i}$.
If
$$
\Sigma_k = \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^k t_i x_i \mid x_i \in \Sigma, t_i \in [0,1], \sum_{i=1}^n t_i = 1\right\} \subset \mathcal{D}(\Sigma)
$$
is the set of all of those formal barycenters of $k$ points, we can endow it with a topology called the [weak topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology), which is the smallest topology such that for any $T \in \Sigma_k$, the map
$$
\langle T,\cdot \rangle \colon f \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\Sigma) \longmapsto \langle T,f\rangle \in \Bbb R
$$
is continuous.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Let $M_1= \delta_{x_i}$, $x_i \in M$, I read about that $M_1$ is a smooth manifold in $C^1(M)^*$. For $\|f\|_{C^1(M)} \leq 1$, the distance is defined by $
dist(\sigma, \hat{\sigma})=\sup _f|(\sigma, f)-(\hat{\sigma}, f)|
.$ Then how to prove the Dirac distribution on a manifold $M$ is a smooth manifold in $C^1(M)^*$, and what is its dimension? Is it dependent on the dimension of the manifold $M$? Can you give me some hints or lectures on it? I have not learned many knowledges on differential geometry, I met this when reading the min-max scheme  in PDE on manifold.

Comment: @YuxuanLi Hi. You should ask this in another question, providing the references where you have read such things so that specialists of the field (which I am not!) can answer you

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I will post another question.